# SQLAlchemy count followers to a tag

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I have a tag model:

```
class tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(240))

    def FollowerRanked(self):        
        #return query(followers, func.count(followers.c.tag_id)).outerjoin(Tag)??
        #return Tag.query.Join(followers, (followers.c.tag_id == self.id).count()??
        #I am not sure how
```

Say I also have a subscriptions table relationship.

```
followers = db.Table('followers',
    db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'))
)
```

I want to loop through Tags... in DESC order for number of followers per tag. I think I need a group_by somewhere.

I want to be able to loop through:

tags.FollowersRanked().items

How do I do this?

EDIT:

Apparently, this becomes difficult to do in the model, so I'm trying to do it in the view instead:

```
tags = db.session.query(models.Tag, \
func.count(models.followers.c.follower_id).label('total'), models.Tag.name, \
models.Tag.title).join(models.followers).group_by(models.Tag).order_by('total DESC')
p = Pagination(tags, page, POSTS_PER_PAGE, tags.count(), tags)
```

The only issue is, it doesn't show tags with 0 subscribers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `join()` to `outerjoin()` and use `coalesce()` to change `NULL`s to `0`s:

```py
tags = db.session.query(
    db.coalesce(db.func.count(models.followers.c.follower_id), 0).label('total'),
    models.Tag.name,
    models.Tag.title
).outerjoin(models.followers).group_by(
    models.Tag.name,
    models.Tag.title
).order_by('total DESC')
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Wow awesome. db.func.coalesce for those trying this.

Comment: `COUNT(expr)` returns the number of times *expr* is not NULL in a group, so `COALESCE()` is not required. It's useful with `SUM()` etc.